# How to make password reset disk windows

Tags: windows, passwords, reset

I don't have floppy drive on my computer.

Is there any way that i can make the password reset disk in a folders so that when i lose my passowrd then i can choose that folder to work as password reset disk.

Is there any other option available beside Floppy drive

Answer (score 5):

A flash drive (thumb stick, thumb drive, whatever you want to call it) should work fine. I've never actually reset my password, but I've sucessfully made one from a USB flash drive. You should be able to pick up a small one for cheap if you don't have one. Really handy things.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a password reset CD instead of a floppy.

See http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ for an image of such a CD.

Download it, and burn it to a blank CD with something like [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm).

Comment: Again, not quite what they're asking. But it *would* do essentially the same thing. Point.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

You can use pretty much anything aside from a Floppy Disk these days.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-password-reset-disk

Answer (score 0):

You can Linux on second partition, and use it to reset Windows password (there are some programs for that for Linux - http://freshmeat.net/projects/chntpw/).

Comment: This isn't quite what they're asking. Re-read the question.